# How to access index.html through Wamp localhost?

Tags: php, localhost, wamp

I have install Wamp on my computer but I can't see my project on my navigator, the Wamp icon is green but when I try to access the file that I put in the www folder trough the virtual LocalHost a blank page is shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check that there is an index page in the first root directory of your project. That is if its a PHP web application there has to be an index.php page in the first root directory of your project.

Second make sure all the services on your wamp server are turned on. Then access your project like this:

http://localhost/yourProjectName/
or
http://localhost/yourProjectName/index.php

Please also check for spelling errors, its very important.